# Angular 2 using php slim endpoints

Tags: angular, post, slim

I have endpoints make it with PHP Slim.

In Angular 1.x I made the calls and works, but in Angular 2 it doesn't.

Angular 1.X: (this works)

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http//localhost:80/Slim/index.php/logina',
  data: $.param({
    email: this.email,
    password:this.password 
   }),
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(function successCallback(sucess){
    // DO SOMETHING
}, function errorCallback(error){
    // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Angular 2:

```
let endpoint = "http://localhost:80/Slim/index.php/logina";
let data = {
    email: username,
    password: password
};

let headers = new Headers(); 
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let options= new RequestOptions({ 
        headers: headers
});
 return this.http.post(endpoint,data, options) 
    .map(response => response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send Post data to Slim API You can use Form Data interface
From Angular2 ,I always use it and you **do not** need to send Headers

Your code will be like that

```
let endpoint = "http://localhost:80/Slim/index.php/logina";
let data = new FormData();
data.append("email",username);
data.append("password",password);
//let headers = new Headers(); 
//headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
//let options= new RequestOptions({ 
        //headers: headers });
 return this.http.post(endpoint,data) 
    .map(response => response.json())
```